# Sample screenspace texture from fragment shader in VR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, fragment-shader, virtual-reality

I've been working on a Unity shader setup that incorporates two visual effects for a VR project.

- A blurred outline glow. This works fine.
- An 'inner glow' type effect. This does not work in VR/stereoscopic, but does work just fine in monoscopic rendering.

[Images and schematic here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxcB5.jpg)

It seems that the red section of this process is not working as expected. When I sample the `Prepass` RenderTexture at the fragment's computed screen position, it does not line up with the model as it is rendered. As a result, the 'inner glow' is offset. Samples that should be within the colored areas fall outside and vice versa.

## Code

**"Red" vert shader:**

```
v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

            // Get screen position of vertex so we can sample _GlowPrePassTex in screenspace
            o.screenpos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
            return o;
        }
```

**"Red" frag shader:**

```
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {               
            // Get rim component
            half tDot = saturate(dot(i.normal, i.viewdir));

            // Sample from _GlowPrePassTex at the fragment's screenspace position
            float2 screenUV = i.screenpos.xy / i.screenpos.w;

            #if UNITY_SINGLE_PASS_STEREO
                float4 scaleOffset = unity_StereoScaleOffset[unity_StereoEyeIndex];
                screenUV = (screenUV - scaleOffset.zw) / scaleOffset.xy;    // I don't know?
            #endif

            fixed4 hlSample = tex2D(_GlowPrePassTex, screenUV);

            // Standard hard rim
            fixed4 col = _RimColor * pow(1.0 - tDot, _RimExponent);

            // Modulate hlSample by (softer) rim strength and add to result
            col += hlSample * pow(1.0 - tDot, _HLExponent);

            return col;
        }
```

## Things I've tried:

I have looked into the samples on [this Unity manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SinglePassStereoRendering.html) and tried the relevant ones (one is included in the fragment shader above), to no avail. I am unsure what each is supposed to achieve and in which order to use them. Sideproblem: if we switch to single pass stereo, a lot of other effects stop working and would need adjustment.

I have also written a version that re-computes the Prepass results within the "red" fragment shader itself and this works. However, at that point we are essentially performing the same (expensive) calculations twice. I would like to avoid this solution if possible.

## Questions:

- Am I trying to do something that fundamentally doesn't work in VR/stereoscopic?
- If not, how do I get the correct screenspace UV coords for a given fragment, to sample from a texture in VR?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're running into a common issue with VR rendering, which is that the screen-space coordinates don't always line up correctly between the two eyes. This is because each eye is rendering the scene from a slightly different perspective, and so the screen-space coordinates for a given fragment can be slightly different for each eye.

The UNITY_SINGLE_PASS_STEREO macro and the unity_StereoScaleOffset variable are Unity's way of handling this issue. In single-pass stereo rendering, both eyes are rendered at the same time, and so the screen-space coordinates need to be adjusted for each eye.

The line of code you've highlighted:

```
    float4 scaleOffset = unity_StereoScaleOffset[unity_StereoEyeIndex];
screenUV = (screenUV - scaleOffset.zw) / scaleOffset.xy;    // I don't know?
```

is doing exactly this. It's adjusting the screen-space coordinates based on which eye is currently being rendered. The unity_StereoEyeIndex variable is either 0 or 1, depending on whether the left or right eye is being rendered. The unity_StereoScaleOffset variable is an array of two float4 values, one for each eye, that contain the necessary scale and offset values to adjust the screen-space coordinates.

If this adjustment isn't working correctly, it could be because the unity_StereoScaleOffset values aren't being set correctly. This could be due to a number of reasons, such as a misconfigured VR camera or a problem with the VR rendering settings.

As for your questions:

No, what you're trying to do should be possible in VR/stereoscopic. It's just a matter of correctly handling the screen-space coordinates for each eye.

The code you've posted should be giving you the correct screen-space UV coordinates for a given fragment in VR. If it's not, then there's likely something else going wrong.